# Convergence rate when a heavierside function is involved

Tags: mathematical-statistics, convergence

Let $\bf \alpha \in {R}^p$ be a parameter, $\bf \alpha_0$ is the true and $\tilde{\bf \alpha}$ is its estimator such that 
$\|\tilde{\bf \alpha} - {\bf \alpha}_0\|_2 = O_p(N^{-r})$,
where $N$ is the sample size.
Let $f(\bf \alpha)$ be a scalar function of $\bf \alpha$, which is smooth with respect to $\bf \alpha$. 
Is it true that 
\begin{equation}
\max \{ 0, f(\tilde{\bf \alpha})\} - \max \{0, f({\bf \alpha}_0)\} = O_p(N^{-r})
\end{equation}
and why?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, $|f(\alpha_0) - f(\tilde{\alpha})| = O_p(N^{-r})$.

We have four possible cases.

When $f(\alpha_0) \ge 0$ and $f(\tilde{\alpha})\ge 0$, 
\begin{equation}
| \max\{0, f(\tilde{\alpha})\} - \max\{0, f({\alpha}_0)\} | =| f(\tilde{\alpha}) - f(\alpha_0)| = O_p(N^{-r}).
\end{equation}

When $f(\alpha_0) < 0$ and $f(\tilde{\alpha})\ge 0$, 
\begin{equation}
|\max\{0, f(\tilde{\alpha})\} - \max\{0, f({\alpha}_0)\}| = |f(\tilde{\alpha}) - 0| \le | f(\tilde{\alpha}) -f(\alpha_0)|  = O_p(N^{-r}).
\end{equation}

When $f(\alpha_0) < 0$ and $f(\tilde{\alpha}) < 0$, 
\begin{equation}
|\max\{0, f(\tilde{\alpha})\} - \max\{0, f({\alpha}_0)\}| = 0.
\end{equation}

When $f(\alpha_0) \ge 0$ and $f(\tilde{\alpha}) < 0$, 
\begin{equation}
|\max\{0, f(\tilde{\alpha})\} - \max\{0, f({\alpha}_0)\}| = | f(\alpha_0)| \le f(\alpha_0) - f(\tilde{\alpha})| =O_p(N^{-r}).
\end{equation}

Here completes the proof.